# OpenGL drawing stretches off the screen when perspective changes

Tags: c#, opengl

I have a simple OpenGL program written in c# using SharpGL.

The program takes a series of points from a file and renders them using the GLBegin/GLEnd method.

That part works fine. My problem arises when I try to change adjust the perspective of the rendering. If I change the size and position of the OpenGLControl, and then call:

```
    public void AdjustPerspective(double width, double height)
    {
        _gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_PROJECTION);
        _gl.LoadIdentity();
        _gl.Perspective(45.0f,  width / height, .1, 400.0);
        _gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_MODELVIEW);
    }
```

The render starts stretching out off the screen. [image: What the problem looks like]

What it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

Now, this doesn't always happen, and it only happens after calling the AdjustPerspective method.

The method is called from an event that is called when the OpenGLControl is resized.

I'm completely at a loss about this because it doesn't always happen. My first thought was that it had something to do with the near plane, but seeing as it doesn't always happen, that can't be it.

My only idea is that glPerspective has some adverse effects when it's called multiple times.

The draw calls are also called from an event, if it helps.

Comment: What's wrong with the image? What do you expect?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll add that to the main post.

Comment: When you resize one other thing that comes to mind is glViewPort. Do you call this with the new size?

Comment: I never called glViewPort, no

Comment: Well, you should. However, I doubt that this is the only problem. But give it a try and post an update.

Comment: No, after setting up the view port in each adjust, it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: The top image above looks like the result of a drawing a textured quad with the repeat mode set to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. Are you rendering to texture, then rendering the texture to the screen (perhaps the OpenGLControl framework does this)?.

Comment: Not that I know of.

I'm doing the bare minumum for drawing the shape. I'm calling glBegin and glEnd, with a loop through a vertex array for the shape and the normals. I didn't touch texturing.

Comment: I fixed it by setting RenderContextMode to RenderContext.NativeWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by setting RenderContextType to SharpGL.RenderContextType.NativeWindow when initializing the OpenGLControls